# Wordpress htaccess in custom PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am currently creating a new website which uses custom PHP code, but i am retrieving Wordpress posts too from a remote wordpress.

In my root folder (as wordpress does), i have the default wordpress .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I also have a index.php file which gives me the posts from WP:

```
<?php
// Include the wp-load'er
include('wp/wp-load.php');


// Get the last 10 posts
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));

...
?>
```

In my project i also have other **custom php** files like **search.php**, **detail.php** etc.

All Wordpress posts links are formatted using slugs like:  **www.mywebsite.com/my-post/**

The question is, how can I change .htaccess file in order to pass index.php a slug parameter when the URL is not a .php file?. (Like index.php?slug=my-post)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that.
I hope that help you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^slug=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mywebsite.com/page/%1.html [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPres
```

Comment: Yes, it is maybe something like that, but it is no working :-(

Answer (score 0):

Thats the solution!:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?slug=$1 [L]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPres
```